# Ubuntu 14.04 stuck at 640x480 resolution

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution

I have recently purchased a system, 
i7 6700, z170 mobo, Nvidia 980 Ti and so on. I set it up for dualboot: win10 & ubuntu 14.04. Although I know my way around a computer, I am not familiar with ubuntu at all except for a few commands years ago.

The goal is to use this system for simulations & learning algorithms, including deep learning. For the latter I require nvidia drivers, cuda and possibly also bumblebee.

Unfortunately, I am currently stuck where my screen resolution is limited to 640x480. I have tried and searched everywhere, including similar questions, but unsuccesful.

This list sums it up:

- PC is connected to TV through HDMI
- installed nvidia 352.38 at first, resolution worked fine
- after bumblebee install I got black screen at restart.
- through restoresession I got back in, but am now stuck at 640x480 "Built-in Display".
- integrated GPU has been blacklisted, so I suspect it is running at the nvidia GPU.

Things tried:

- installed & tried nvidia 352 and 358 (tried to solve issue by updating to no avail)
- nvidia-settings can be run, but it has no filled in options & cannot find registry key file
- xorg.conf changed, adopted, removed but no success.
- attempted extra modes through xrandr. Although resolutions have been added, they could not be selected. Xrandr repeatedly claims 'failed to get size of gamma for output default'
- changed kernel through grub: i915.preliminary_hw_support = 1, no effect
- nvidia-xconfig command was not found, but I could find it on my PC: /usr/lib/nvidia-358/bin/nvidia-xconfig. I ran and got a xorg.conf but it did not have any effect, nor after I modified it with extra screen resolutions.

Currently, I am at a loss and could really use some help to get this ubuntu on track! I will really appreciate any help!
Cheers,
AIworks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the nvidia drivers are blacklisted (prevented from loading during boot). You mentioned that it happened after installing bumblebee, so obviously something went wrong when installing this. It is possible for the bumblebee installation to blacklist the nvidia drivers. To revert the bumblebee installation, please check if `/etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf` exists, If so, make a backup if this file, and then remove it.

```
sudo cp /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf ~/
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf
```

Reboot to update the changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that the nvidia driver did not install, since you have no options in the nvidia-settings.

Try this first in a terminal :

> sudo apt-get install nvidia-352

If it goes into download/install after, then your nvidia driver was not installed yet.

Comment: Thanks for you comment.
nvidia-358 is installed:
output:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-358 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.

To clarify, I have options in the nvidia-settings, but simply no profile.

Comment: Also: the issue initially occured with 352. Ive 358 now as it is one way I tried to fix the issue